# How to determine a cycle period or peak to peak period value from ACF in python

Tags: python, time-series, advanced-custom-fields

Everyone

I try to automatically determine a cycle period value from ACF in python because I have to use this value for calculating time windows size for LSTM time series forecasting models. For Example, the ACF graph below shows 96 lags from the first peak value to the second peak value.

[image]

My propose to extract integer '96' from ACF automatically.

Do you have any ideas to achieve my goal?

Comment: If your data is very well behaved, you can look at the difference in timestamps between local maxima

Comment: @DerekO appreciate. your answer very helpful for me.